# can't upload updated react native app into play store

Tags: react-native, google-play

Yesterday I've finished and uploaded into play store a react native app (I've followed [these](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) steps).

Today I've made some changes to the app and I tried to upload into the play store the new version (I changed `versionCode` and `versionName` inside build.gradle file).

When I try to upload the new .apk file in the play store I get this error message:

```
You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate. Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s)
```

Comment: try generating with a new signing key. It will work

Comment: i think you have signed your apk with different key. make sure you use previous one

Comment: @Ankush Rishi Do you mean: keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000    ?  because I've already tried and it asks me for passwords. If I insert the passwords I used yesterday for the very first build then it makes the build else it will fail. So when I enter the right passwords the apk gets generated but if I upload to the play store I receive the error message of the question.